# How to improve query execution time?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, rdbms

I have a rather complex query, which takes 1-2 minutes to execute. Is there a way to improve execution time?

Here is the query:

```
select  o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, s.orders_status_name,
        ot.text as order_total, ot.value, DATEDIFF(NOW(), payment_data_read_status) as numDaysLeft,
        ( SELECT  ifnull(sum(op.paid_amount), 0)
            from  orders_payment op
            where  op.orders_id=o.orders_id
              AND  op.confirm_payment='1'
        ) as paid_total
    from  orders o, orders_total ot, orders_status s
    where  o.orders_id = ot.orders_id
      and  ot.class = 'ot_total'
      and  o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
      and  s.language_id = '1'
      AND  ROUND(ot.value,2) != ROUND(
                ( SELECT  ifnull(sum(op.paid_amount),0)
                    from  orders_payment op
                    where  op.orders_id=o.orders_id
                      AND  op.confirm_payment='1'
                ), 2)
```

### Query Explanation

[image]

### Some details

> number of records in orders = 7321
>
> number of records in orders_total = 22167
>
> number of records in orders_payment= 12038
>
> number of records in orders_status= 9

orders_id column is auto increment in orders table. Firstly I thought to index orders_id column in orders table but as it is primary so I don't think it will work.

**EDITS**
Error

[image]

Comment: You could get rid of subqueries for example.... split them into different queries

Comment: You have better chance to solve your question about query performance on [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And please, for the future, **do not** post pictures unless visuals are important. Copy/Paste any text you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that nested queries are not necessarily bad, but I try to avoid putting them in the select list.  This is my suggestion:

```
select
    o.orders_id,
    o.customers_id,
    o.customers_name,
    s.orders_status_name, 
    ot.text as order_total, 
    ot.value, 
    datediff(now(), payment_data_read_status) as numdaysleft, 
    ifnull(op.paid_total, 0) paid_total
from
    orders o
    join
    orders_total ot
    on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id 
    join
    orders_status s
    on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
    left outer join
    (
        select 
            orders_id,
            sum(ifnull(paid_amount, 0)) as paid_total
        from
            orders_payment 
        where
            confirm_payment = '1'
        group by
            orders_id
    ) op 
    on
        op.orders_id = o.orders_id
where
    ot.class = 'ot_total' and 
    s.language_id = '1' and
    round(ot.value,2) != round(ifnull(op.paid_total, 0), 2);
```

I think this will give the optimizer a better chance to do a good job.

Notice that I have put a "group by" in the inner query for "op".  Without that I think you may trick the optimiser into running this query for every result row rather than just once.

With the volumes you have you should not need any indexes; they would probably make things worse rather than better, but test it and  see what happens.

I haven't been able to test my suggestion, but if you provide create table scripts and some data, I would do that.  Apologies if I've made any typos in the query.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your solution and its giving me couple of errors. I have attached the screenshot in edits.

Comment: I was afraid I would do that; it's always better to test.  I've taken out the  ",0)" in the last line that was left over from the "if null", because this is not needed there now, it is done already in the inner query.  I think that's it.

Comment: I tried a few changes in your query and its still giving me syntax errors. Here is the [link](http://testing.gemwares.com/tests.php) for you to test the query. thanks

Comment: Great, it makes so much difference to be able to test.  I think the query as it stands above now does what you want.  Before, both answers were ignoring the cases where paid_total is null or zero.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by Ron Ballard, but doing the rounding in the sub query, and switching to explicit join syntax:-

```
SELECT o.orders_id, 
        o.customers_id, 
        o.customers_name, 
        s.orders_status_name, 
        ot.text as order_total, 
        ot.value, 
        DATEDIFF(NOW(), payment_data_read_status) as numDaysLeft, 
        sub0.paid_amount_sum as paid_total 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders_total ot ON o.orders_id = ot.orders_id
INNER JOIN orders_status s ON o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT orders_id,
            COALESCE(SUM(op.paid_amount),0) AS paid_amount_sum,
            ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(op.paid_amount),0), 2) AS paid_amount_sum_rounded
    FROM orders_payment op 
    WHERE op.confirm_payment = '1'
    GROUP BY orders_id
) sub0
ON sub0.orders_id = o.orders_id 
WHERE ot.class = 'ot_total' 
AND s.language_id = '1' 
AND ROUND(ot.value,2) != sub0.paid_amount_sum_rounded
```

Comment: thanks for considering my question. The query I posted in the question returns me 215 records while your modified query is returning just 55 records. yes the execution time has marvelously improved to just a blink of an eye.
Is there any information you need from myside to test your query result ?

Comment: Would need to see some data to have a play with, and the table declares. I might have missed something but can't see why my solution should bring back less records so would need a bit of a play

Comment: I am creating an interface for you to test the query result. Will send you the link shortly.

Comment: you can test the number of records returned by your query from this [link](http://testing.gemwares.com/tests.php)

this will return 233 records if you run my original query while yours is returning only 55

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem with 233 results vs 55 is the test `... != ...` where one of them could be `NULL`.  That returns `NULL`, which is treated as false, hence as if `=`.

One way to fix that is to add

```
AND sub0.paid_amount_sum_rounded IS NOT NULL
```

Indexes needed:

```
o:  INDEX(orders_status, orders_id)  -- in this order
ot:  INDEX(class, orders_id)  -- in either order
```

Take-aways from this and other answers:

- Use `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.  (This is for clarity; it has no impact on performance.)
- Watch out for `LEFT JOIN` and subqueries with respect to possible `NULL` outcomes.
- Avoid subqueries in `WHERE`.
- Be sure to have suitable indexes (to avoid the table scans that were killing performance).
- Understand the benefit of 'composite' indexes.